# Exclude tags from gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental

Tags: javascript, wordpress, graphql, gatsby, headless-cms

when I build my Gatsby website using datas fetched with "gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental" plugin, then I can see during build that the plugin fetch tags:
"**success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Tag - 91.763s - fetched 502**"

There's many tags and it costs a lot of time, but I don't need it / use it in my project.

**I setup a Gatsby configuration in gatsby-config.js file like so to avoid fetching tags:**

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental",
  options: {
    url: "https://my.website.io/graphql",
    type: {
      Post: {
        limit: 100,
      },
    },
    excludedRoutes: ["**/tags", "**/taxonomies", "**/users"], // <= see here excluded routes
    includedRoutes: ["**/products"],
  },
},
```

***But it still fetch tags. I think that I did that according to the docs but what I am doing wrong ?***

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental/blob/master/docs/plugin-options.md#excludefieldnames-array) you can pass an array to exclude the field names like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental`,
    options: {
        excludeFieldNames: [`tag1`, `tag2`],
  },
},
```

Besides, `excludedRoutes` is a configuration only allowed in [`gatsby source-wordpress`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-wordpress/), not in the experimental version.

Comment: Thank you Ferran for your answer. But, I have more than 500 tags. I don't want to mention the ones I don't need. I want to exclude all tags. Otherwise, I don't think that it is a good idea to mention 500 tags to exclude in my Gatsby config.
This should exclude all tags: excludedRoutes: ["**/tags", "**/taxonomies", "**/users"], but it doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Ok, in fact, "excludedRoutes" option only exists in gatsby-source-wordpress, and not in experimental version ! I'll have to ask to clean the Wordpress database or I will mention thoses hundreds of tags. Thank you